# ❴eslint_d❵ [eslint] Error: Failed to load plugin 'import declared in '.eslintrc.js

Tags: typescript, eslint, neovim, eslintrc

**I use neovim to develop TypeScript, I upgraded eslint 8.28.0 When I opened neovim it got an error, I tried many times to solve it, but still could not solve this problem, please ask for help**

```
❴eslint_d❵ [eslint] Error: Failed to load plugin 'import declared in '.eslintrc.js » eslint-config-semistandard »
 eslint-config-standard': Cannot find module 'eslint' Require stack: 
    - /Users/jornajan/Coding/bilibili/muke/miProject/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js 
    - /Users/jornajan/Coding/bilibili/muke/miProject/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/named.js
```

```
$ node -v
18.12.1

$ npm -v
9.1.3
```

[image]

How to fix this, I don't know if this is a bug or not

Comment: first try to downgrade eslint to 7. If that does work, google for issues of slkint-neovim compability on github

Answer (score 10):

Open the terminal and run `eslint_d restart` and **restart neovim**

Comment: Worked to me lol thx

Comment: Hours and hours of search and this fixed it...

Comment: it works for me) I have eslitn_d installed with Mason, so in nvim I run:
:!eslint_d restart
:qall
than I restart nvim
$ nvim 
and it works. Thank you)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. `eslint_d` is installed using `Mason` and `eslint:8.34.0`. I tried delete `~/.eslint_d` file and restart `eslint_d` using `eslint_d restart`. `eslint_d` located in `~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/eslint_d`. So I dont understand what help me

Also there is a github issue: https://github.com/mantoni/eslint_d.js/issues/235

Comment: 1. install eslint_d globally with npm or pnpm.
2. MasonUninstall eslint_d
3. eslint_d restart